# Removing extra spaces in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[image: chart]

You can notice that there are many unwanted space (in the left,top and bottom too) in the chart. How to clear them ?

```
var options = {
                     'width':500,
                     'height':400

          };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the top and left spacing for your chart, and also the width and height.

Try :

```
var options = {
    chartArea: {
        left: 20,
        top: 30,
        width: 500,
        height: 300
    }
};
```

See a [demo of it here](https://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/z4vrgyhy/).

And you can also use percentages, like this :

```
var options = {
    chartArea: {
        left: '10%',
        top: '5%',
        width: '60%',
        height: '80%'
    }
};
```